# how to print text pattern with c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make this text output in C

[The output i need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHEng.png)

so far i only manage to make this which only made the left part of the first alphabet

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf(" * ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

any idea how to complete the H part?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how i'd have done it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
            if (j < 3 || i >= 4 && i < 6 && j < 9 || j >=9 && j < 12 || j >= 16 && j < 19 || i < 6 && (j-i >= 19 && j-i < 22 || j+i >= 30 && j+i < 33) || j >= 33 && j < 36 || j >= 40 && (j < 43 || i < 2 || i >= 4 && i < 6 || i >= 8))
                putchar('X');
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

outer for loop prints 10 lines.
inner for loop prints 52 characters in each line, deciding whether to print an 'X' or a space depending on what is the current number of line and character.

the zero-indexed places where an X needs to be printed are:

## j < 3

characters 0-2 in every line

## i >= 4 && i < 6 && j < 9

characters 0-8 in lines 4-5

## j >= 9 && j < 12 || j >= 16 && j < 19

characters 9-11 and 16-18 in every line

## i < 6 && (j-i >= 19 && j-i < 22 || j+i >= 30 && j+i < 33)

this is the trickiest part that prints the "v" shape in the "M". try and figure out for yourself how.

## j >= 33 && j < 36

characters 33-35 in every line

## j >= 40 && (j < 43 || i < 2 || i >= 4 && i < 6 || i >= 8)

characters 40-42 in every line and characters 40-end in lines 0-1, 4-5, 8-end

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm still new here